# on Back pressed doesnt work

Tags: android

This is my MainActivity which I use to open a webview via Imagebutton.

But I Need to integrate a "backpress function"

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.metehan.hbc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewactivity_webview);
        wb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.webviewactivity_imagebutton);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wb.loadUrl("https://elearns02.fh-biberach.de/ilias3/login.php?target=&soap_pw=&ext_uid=&cookies=nocookies&client_id=HSBC&lang=de");
            }
        });
        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                ib.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                wb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }}
```

Comment: Also you may want to tag this as android and java. Just a tip

Comment: Sidenote: [StackOverflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum)

Answer (score 0):

If you opened the new activity from `startActivityForResult`, you can just call `finish()`.

If that doesn't work then `android:noHistory = "true"` is set to `android:noHistory = "false"` in your AndroidManifest.xml.

If the above does not work then try calling `finish()` in your main activity before you switch to the new activity.

For your case try:

```
package com.example.metehan.hbc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewactivity_webview);
        wb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.webviewactivity_imagebutton);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wb.loadUrl("https://elearns02.fh-biberach.de/ilias3/login.php?target=&soap_pw=&ext_uid=&cookies=nocookies&client_id=HSBC&lang=de");
            }
        });
        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                ib.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                wb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    }}
```

Comment: could you Show it to me in a Code? im really new^^ but thx for the fast answer

Comment: I'm not on my main computer, but here is a attempt. Just try playing around with it and see if anything works. Struggling is natural with programming and it happens to everybody.

Comment: i tried the Code but @Override is called "Annotations are not allowed here"